# retrieve multiple files from a java GUI

Tags: java, database, user-interface

So im working on a project where im supposed to dynamically load the contents of a .csv file into the database.I have been hard coding the path of the file till now like

*inserted = insertFromFile("C:/Users/Student/Desktop/Book1.csv",connection, "customer");*

however now i have to read multiple files from a folder and integrate the program with a GUI.
I have 2 questions:

a)how do i read multiple files from a folder
b)how do i retrieve the path of a file for the insert statement

any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The Java [tutorial on File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) is an excellent resource to start with. To read multiple files from a folder, you could set up your file chooser so that you could select only directories. This would assume that you wanted to load *all* files from that folder. Otherwise, you could have your own logic as to which file extensions to load.

If you wanted only a subset of certain files in a folder, you'd need to allow for multi-selection in the File Chooser.

The same tutorial will show you how to retrieve the filename(s) selected, but the short answer is: you call `getSelectedFiles()`